# QueryAddRow throwing error in Coldfusion Webservice

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am facing a weird issue.

When I am consuming the below snippet of code as a webservice residing in a CF9 server I am getting the error "**The value coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be converted to a number**."

The call returns an array of structures. I would like to create a query from this array of structure. When I place this code as a standalone code in my local server(CF10) it works fine. But as soon i place it in the remote server to be invoked i get the error.

I almost pulled out my hair when I got the same error message even when I replaced the variable 'tempstruct' with a hard coded structure. As soon I remove the QueryAddRow I am able to return anything.

Any help is appreciated.

```
<cfset myquery=querynew("category,category_id,event_description","varchar,integer,varchar")>
<cfinvoke 
  webservice="http://199.99.99.999/vod_queries.cfc?wsdl"
  method="getAllCategoryByResort" 
  returnvariable="arrAllSpaEvents"
  refreshwsdl="true" >
  <cfinvokeargument name="Resort" value="SRB" >
</cfinvoke>
<cfif arraylen(arrAllSpaEvents) GT 0>
  <cfloop array="#arrAllSpaEvents#" index="cur_row">
    <cfset tempstruct=StructNew()>
    <cfset tempstruct.CATEGORY=cur_row.CATEGORY>
    <cfset tempstruct.CATEGORY_ID=cur_row.CATEGORY_ID>
    <cfset tempstruct.EVENT_DESCRIPTION=cur_row.EVENT_DESCRIPTION>
    <cfset QueryAddRow(myquery,#tempstruct#)>   
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
<cfreturn myquery>
```

Comment: You're trying to use CF10 functionality on CF9. See https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/QueryAddRow

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I am afraid that may not be right. I ran this code in a CF9 server as a standalone code and it worked. The only difference was i did not invoke it as a remote functionality but just from a cfc.

Comment: QueryAddRow is supported by CF9! http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d1b.html

Comment: Does the error occur on the cfc or on the code after you invoke it?

Comment: Read the docs! _"**Enhancements in ColdFusion 10** lets you specify a struct, an array of structs, or arrays."_ In CF9, only an integer was supported.

Comment: Neither CF9.0.1 (build 9,0,1,274733) nor Cf9.0.2 (9,0,2,282541) accept a struct to QueryAddRow.

Comment: @DanBracuk: the error occurs on invocation.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I am not sure of the documentation and blogs whgen I can see my code running perfectly fine when run on Version 9,0,0,251028. I am not inviting a row :-) but it is totally a mysterious bug. Please try to understand. Again i tried for a different approach just for the sake of aggregating the multiple array of structure into a new array. The arrayappend of an array of structures also showed similar behaviour. The code worked fine on CF9 but not when put in CF9 remote. I strongly believe there is a behavioural difference in the code when used as a webservice.

Comment: Firstly, 9,0,0,251028 is the first unpatched release of CF9, right? It has [numerous security vulnerabilities](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-53/product_id-8739/version_id-85858/Adobe-Coldfusion-9.0.html) - go get patched!

Comment: That aside, if it works on CF9.0.0 it is unofficial and unsupported - and thus any inconsistent behaviour is unsurprising. The only valid solution is to use it the supported way (or upgrade to CF10/Railo).

Comment: @PeterBoughton: Thanks Peter, i think this might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got. 
However, indeed you are using new CF10 overloading in CF9. What's more, if you were using CF10, it looks like you could stuff the whole top array in with looping like that. 
But you can almost do the same thing. CF9 will take an array overload for the value. 
Not quite as clean as CF10 but you do what you can.

Also, the extra # signs are superfluous.

Here is an example with something that your data might look like:

```
<cfscript> // I did this all in a cfscript block for simplicity
```

Your retrieved data might look something like this guessin from example

```
    arrAllSpaEvents = [
        {category='fun', category_id=1, event_description='massage'},
        {category='work', category_id=2, event_description='spinning'},
        {category='beauty', category_id=3, event_description='mani'},
        {category='beauty', category_id=3, event_description='pedi'}
    ];
```

Create a more useful struct to build the query dynamically

```
    s = {
        category = {colType = 'varchar', colVals = []},
        category_id = {colType = 'integer', colVals = []},
        event_description = {colType = 'varchar', colVals = []}
    };
```

This is looping the data to fill the colVals arrays

```
    for(c = 1; c <= arrAllSpaEvents.size(); c++ ) {
        for(k in arrAllSpaEvents[c]) {
            s[k].colVals[c] = arrAllSpaEvents[c][k];
        }
    }
```

This is the short form of the same double loop above in a single line

```
    for(c = 1; c <= arrAllSpaEvents.size(); c++ ) for(k in arrAllSpaEvents[c]) s[k].colVals[c] = arrAllSpaEvents[c][k];
```

Now build your query. Start with an empty query (pass in a blank);

```
    q = queryNew('');
```

Then loop your struct and using the keys for the column names (for simplicity they are the same key)

```
    for(k in s ) queryAddColumn(q,k,s[k].colType,s[k].colVals);
```

Verify your struct and query:

```
    writedump(s);
    writedump(q);


</cfscript>
```

I ran this in CF9 so should work fine for you.

This should get you going.